# undefined reference to many pkgs

Tags: ros2, rclcpp

I just started out with ROS 2.0. I am unsure if I am doing something stupid or missing out something. However, I can’t build these files. If I should have posted somewhere else kindly let me know.
i'm struggle with it already for a week, I hope someone can solve it for me, thank you very much

The command used for building:
colcon build

```
Error thrown:
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sign_detection.dir/src/sign_detection.cpp.o: in function `main':
sign_detection.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `rclcpp::shutdown(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Context>, std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sign_detection.dir/src/sign_detection.cpp.o: in function `rclcpp::ParameterTypeException::ParameterTypeException(rclcpp::ParameterType, rclcpp::ParameterType)':
sign_detection.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp22ParameterTypeExceptionC2ENS_13ParameterTypeES1_[_ZN6rclcpp22ParameterTypeExceptionC5ENS_13ParameterTypeES1_]+0x3e): undefined reference to `rclcpp::to_string(rclcpp::ParameterType)'
/usr/bin/ld: sign_detection.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp22ParameterTypeExceptionC2ENS_13ParameterTypeES1_[_ZN6rclcpp22ParameterTypeExceptionC5ENS_13ParameterTypeES1_]+0x50): undefined reference to `rclcpp::to_string(rclcpp::ParameterType)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sign_detection.dir/src/sign_detection.cpp.o: in function `auto rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter<double>(std::string const&, double const&, rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor_<std::allocator<void> > const&, bool)':
sign_detection.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp4Node17declare_parameterIdEEDaRKSsRKT_RKN14rcl_interfaces3msg20ParameterDescriptor_ISaIvEEEb[_ZN6rclcpp4Node17declare_parameterIdEEDaRKSsRKT_RKN14rcl_interfaces3msg20ParameterDescriptor_ISaIvEEEb]+0x8e): undefined reference to `rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter(std::string const&, rclcpp::ParameterValue const&, rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor_<std::allocator<void> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sign_detection.dir/src/sign_detection_node.cpp.o: in function `SignDetectionNode::SignDetectionNode()':
sign_detection_node.cpp:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `libpsaf::SignDetectionInterface::SignDetectionInterface(std::string, unsigned int, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, std::string, std::string, std::string, rclcpp::QoS)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sign_detection.dir/src/sign_detection_node.cpp.o: in function `SignDetectionNode::publishImageWithBoundin
```

this is sign_detection_node.cpp

```
/**
 * @file sign_detection_node.cpp
 * @brief the implementation of the SignDetectionNode class
 * @author PSAF
 * @date 2022-06-01
 */
#include "psaf_sign_detection/sign_detection_node.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

SignDetectionNode::SignDetectionNode()
: SignDetectionInterface(
    SIGN_DETECTION_NODE_NAME,
    NBR_OF_CAMS_RGB,
    CAM_TOPIC_RGB,
    STATE_TOPIC,
    SIGN_TOPIC,
    STATUS_INFO_TOPIC,
    rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::KeepLast {10})
){
   // load model
  try {
    module_ = torch::jit::load("/home/tuodou/wise-2023-24-ctrl-alt-defeat-feature-lane-detection/src/psaf_sign_detection/models/yolov5n.torchscript");
  } catch (const c10::Error & e) {
    std::cerr << "error loading the model\n";
  }
  std::cout << "Model Loading OK\n";
  module_.eval();

  // load sign names
  std::ifstream infile("/home/tuodou/wise-2023-24-ctrl-alt-defeat-feature-lane-detection/src/psaf_sign_detection/models/sign.names");
  if (infile.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
      class_names_.emplace_back(line);
    }
    infile.close();
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Error loading the class names!\n";
  }

  // set parameters
  conf_threshold_ = 0.4;
  iou_threshold_ = 0.5;
}


void SignDetectionNode::processImage(cv::Mat & img, int sensor)
{
  // save time and current speed
  // auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // double speed = current_speed_;
  cv::Size original_size = img.size();

// #ifdef DEBUG_IMAGE
//   // create a clone of the image to not change the original image
//   cv::Mat img_clone = img.clone();
// #endif

  // resize image to have the wanted size with boundaries
  std::vector<float> pad_info = getLetterboxImage(img, img, cv::Size(640, 640));
  const float pad_w = pad_info[0];
  const float pad_h = pad_info[1];
  const float scale = pad_info[2];

  // normalization 1/255
  img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC3, 1.0f / 255.0f);
  // convert image to tensor
  auto tensor_img = torch::from_blob(img.data, {1, img.rows, img.cols, img.channels()});
  tensor_img = tensor_img.permute({0, 3, 1, 2}).contiguous();

  // create input vector
  std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
  inputs.emplace_back(tensor_img);

  // perform forward pass through yolo network
  torch::jit::IValue output = module_.forward(inputs);

  // post process the detections
  torch::Tensor detections = output.toTuple()->elements()[0].toTensor();
  std::vector<Detection> result = postProcessing(
    detections, pad_w, pad_h, scale, original_size,
    conf_threshold_, iou_threshold_);
  // auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

  // iterate through all detections
  // for (const Detection & sign_detect : result) {
  //   // create a sign message
  //   publishSignMessage(sign_detect, duration.count(), speed);
  // }

// #ifdef DEBUG_IMAGE
//   publishImageWithBoundingBox(img_clone, result, class_names_);
// #endif
}
int SignDetectionNode::mapDetToSignType(int detection)
{
  // determine correct sign type
  int out_sign;
  switch (detection) {
    case 0:
      std::cout << "STOP" << std::endl;
      out_sign = STOP_SIGN;
      break;
    case 1:
      std::cout << "PEDESTRIAN" << std::endl;
      out_sign = PEDESTRIAN_SIGN;
      break;
    case 2:
      std::cout << "YIELD" << std::endl;
      out_sign = YIELD_SIGN;
      break;
    case 3:
      std::cout << "ZONE_30" << std::endl;
      out_sign = LIMIT_30_SIGN;
      break;
    case 4:
      std::cout << "END_ZONE_30" << std::endl;
      out_sign = END_LIMIT_30_SIGN;
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "Such a sign is not defined" << std::endl;
      break;
  }
  return out_sign;
}
void SignDetectionNode::updateState(std_msgs::msg::Int64::SharedPtr state)
{
  (void) state;
}

void SignDetectionNode::update()
{

}

void SignDetectionNode::publishImageWithBoundingBox(
  cv::Mat & img,
  const std::vector<Detection> & detections,
  const std::vector<std::string> & class_names,
  bool label)
{
  // only if something was detected
  if (!detections.empty()) {
    // iterate through all detections
    for (const auto & detection : detections) {
      const auto & box = detection.bbox;
      float score = detection.score;
      int class_idx = detection.class_idx;

      // draw rectangle
      cv::rectangle(img, box, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

      // draw label
      if (label) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << score;
        std::string s = class_names[class_idx] + " " + ss.str();

        auto font_face = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX;
        auto font_scale = 1.0;
        int thickness = 1;
        int baseline = 0;
        auto s_size = cv::getTextSize(s, font_face, font_scale, thickness, &baseline);
        cv::rectangle(
          img,
          cv::Point(box.tl().x, box.tl().y - s_size.height - 5),
          cv::Point(box.tl().x + s_size.width, box.tl().y),
          cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
        cv::putText(
          img, s, cv::Point(box.tl().x, box.tl().y - 5),
          font_face, font_scale, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness);
      }
    }
  }

  // publish image
  // this->publishImage(img, "camera_link");
}

std::vector<Detection> SignDetectionNode::postProcessing(
  const torch::Tensor & detections,
  float pad_w, float pad_h, float scale, const cv::Size & img_shape,
  float conf_thres, float iou_thres)
{
  constexpr int item_attr_size = 5;
  // number of classes, e.g. 5 for our dataset
  auto num_classes = detections.size(2) - item_attr_size;

  // get candidates which object confidence > threshold
  auto conf_mask = detections.select(2, 4).ge(conf_thres).unsqueeze(2);

  // apply constrains to get filtered detections for current image
  auto det = torch::masked_select(detections[0], conf_mask[0]).view(
    {-1, num_classes + item_attr_size});

  // declare detection vector
  std::vector<Detection> det_vec;

  // only do processing if a sign was detected
  if (det.size(0) != 0) {
    // compute overall score = obj_conf * cls_conf, similar to x[:, 5:] *= x[:, 4:5]
    det.slice(1, item_attr_size, item_attr_size + num_classes) *= det.select(1, 4).unsqueeze(1);

    // box (center x, center y, width, height) to (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    torch::Tensor box = xywh2xyxy(det.slice(1, 0, 4));

    // [best class only] get the max classes score at each result (e.g. elements 5-84)
    std::tuple<torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor> max_classes =
      torch::max(det.slice(1, item_attr_size, item_attr_size + num_classes), 1);

    // class score and index
    auto max_conf_score = std::get<0>(max_classes);
    auto max_conf_index = std::get<1>(max_classes);

    max_conf_score = max_conf_score.to(torch::kFloat).unsqueeze(1);
    max_conf_index = max_conf_index.to(torch::kFloat).unsqueeze(1);

    // shape: n * 6, top-left x/y (0,1), bottom-right x/y (2,3), score(4), class index(5)
    det = torch::cat({box.slice(1, 0, 4), max_conf_score, max_conf_index}, 1);

    // for batched NMS
    constexpr int max_wh = 4096;
    auto c = det.slice(1, item_attr_size, item_attr_size + 1) * max_wh;
    auto offset_box = det.slice(1, 0, 4) + c;

    // define vectors
    std::vector<cv::Rect> offset_box_vec;
    std::vector<float> score_vec;
    const auto & det_array = det.accessor<float, 2>();

    // use accessor to access tensor elements efficiently
    tensor2Detection(
      offset_box.accessor<float, 2>(), det_array, offset_box_vec, score_vec);

    // run non maximum suppression
    std::vector<int> nms_indices;
    cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(offset_box_vec, score_vec, conf_thres, iou_thres, nms_indices);

    // iterate through all remaining detections
    for (int index : nms_indices) {
      Detection t;
      const auto & b = det_array[index];
      t.bbox = cv::Rect(
        cv::Point(b[Det::tl_x], b[Det::tl_y]),
        cv::Point(b[Det::br_x], b[Det::br_y]));
      t.score = det_array[index][Det::score];
      t.class_idx = det_array[index][Det::class_idx];
      det_vec.emplace_back(t);
    }

    // scale coordinates to original image size
    scaleCoordinates(det_vec, pad_w, pad_h, scale, img_shape);
  }

  return det_vec;
}

void SignDetectionNode::scaleCoordinates(
  std::vector<Detection> & data, float pad_w, float pad_h,
  float scale, const cv::Size & img_shape)
{
  // define lambda function for clipping
  auto clip = [](float n, float lower, float upper) {
      return std::max(lower, std::min(n, upper));
    };

  std::vector<Detection> detections;
  // iterate through all detections in data
  for (auto & i : data) {
    // calculate scaled coordinates
    float x1 = (i.bbox.tl().x - pad_w) / scale;  // x padding
    float y1 = (i.bbox.tl().y - pad_h) / scale;  // y padding
    float x2 = (i.bbox.br().x - pad_w) / scale;  // x padding
    float y2 = (i.bbox.br().y - pad_h) / scale;  // y padding

    // apply clipping
    x1 = clip(x1, 0, img_shape.width);
    y1 = clip(y1, 0, img_shape.height);
    x2 = clip(x2, 0, img_shape.width);
    y2 = clip(y2, 0, img_shape.height);

    // create bounding box
    i.bbox = cv::Rect(cv::Point(x1, y1), cv::Point(x2, y2));
  }
}

torch::Tensor SignDetectionNode::xywh2xyxy(const torch::Tensor & x)
{
  auto y = torch::zeros_like(x);
  // convert bounding box format from (center x, center y, width, height) to (x1, y1, x2, y2)
  y.select(1, Det::tl_x) = x.select(1, 0) - x.select(1, 2).div(2);
  y.select(1, Det::tl_y) = x.select(1, 1) - x.select(1, 3).div(2);
  y.select(1, Det::br_x) = x.select(1, 0) + x.select(1, 2).div(2);
  y.select(1, Det::br_y) = x.select(1, 1) + x.select(1, 3).div(2);
  return y;
}

void SignDetectionNode::tensor2Detection(
  const at::TensorAccessor<float, 2> & offset_boxes,
  const at::TensorAccessor<float, 2> & det,
  std::vector<cv::Rect> & offset_box_vec,
  std::vector<float> & score_vec)
{
  // iterate all tensor boxes
  for (int i = 0; i < offset_boxes.size(0); i++) {
    offset_box_vec.emplace_back(
      cv::Rect(
        cv::Point(offset_boxes[i][Det::tl_x], offset_boxes[i][Det::tl_y]),
        cv::Point(offset_boxes[i][Det::br_x], offset_boxes[i][Det::br_y]))
    );
    score_vec.emplace_back(det[i][Det::score]);
  }
}

std::vector<float> SignDetectionNode::getLetterboxImage(
  const cv::Mat & src, cv::Mat & dst,
  const cv::Size & out_size)
{
  auto in_h = static_cast<float>(src.rows);
  auto in_w = static_cast<float>(src.cols);
  float out_h = out_size.height;
  float out_w = out_size.width;

  // find scaling factor
  float scale = std::min(out_w / in_w, out_h / in_h);

  // calculate middle points
  int mid_h = static_cast<int>(in_h * scale);
  int mid_w = static_cast<int>(in_w * scale);

  // resize image to wanted size
  cv::resize(src, dst, cv::Size(mid_w, mid_h));

  // calculate boundaries of letterbox
  int top = (static_cast<int>(out_h) - mid_h) / 2;
  int down = (static_cast<int>(out_h) - mid_h + 1) / 2;
  int left = (static_cast<int>(out_w) - mid_w) / 2;
  int right = (static_cast<int>(out_w) - mid_w + 1) / 2;

  // create letterbox image
  cv::copyMakeBorder(
    dst, dst, top, down, left, right, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,
    cv::Scalar(114, 114, 114));

  // return left and top boundary and scale
  std::vector<float> pad_info{static_cast<float>(left), static_cast<float>(top), scale};
  return pad_info;
}
```

this is sign_detection.cpp

```
/**
 * @file sign_detection.cpp
 * @brief the main method for the sign detection. This function gets called by the launch file
 * @author PSAF
 * @date 2022-06-01
 */
#include <memory>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "psaf_sign_detection/sign_detection_node.hpp"

/**
* Main: Start the Sign Detection Node
*/

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  std::shared_ptr<SignDetectionNode> node = std::make_shared<SignDetectionNode>();
  rclcpp::WallRate rate(node->declare_parameter("update_frequency", rclcpp::PARAMETER_DOUBLE)
    .get<rclcpp::ParameterType::PARAMETER_DOUBLE>());
  while (rclcpp::ok()) {
    rclcpp::spin_some(node);
    node->update();
    rate.sleep();
  }

  rclcpp::shutdown();
}
```

hpp is here:

```
/**
 * @file sign_detection_node.hpp
 * @brief The definition of the SignDetectionNode class
 * @author PSAF
 * @date 2022-06-01
 */
#ifndef PSAF_SIGN_DETECTION__SIGN_DETECTION_NODE_HPP_
#define PSAF_SIGN_DETECTION__SIGN_DETECTION_NODE_HPP_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "libpsaf/interface/sign_detection_interface.hpp"
#include "psaf_configuration/configuration.hpp"
#include "psaf_sign_detection/definitions.hpp"
#include "libpsaf_msgs/msg/sign.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/float64.hpp"
#include "torch/script.h"
#include "torch/torch.h"


/**
 * @class SignDetectionNode
 * @implements SignDetectionInterface
 * @brief Detect the signs located next to the road.
 * @details This class is the node of the sign detection. It is responsible for
 *          the detection of signs and the publishing of the detected signs.
 */
class SignDetectionNode : public libpsaf::SignDetectionInterface
{
public:
  SignDetectionNode();

  /**
   * @brief Method in which the results get published
   * @details This method is called periodically by the main method of the node.
   */
  void update();

protected:
  /**
   * @brief Callback Method for the image topic
   * @param[in] img the image
   * @param[in] sensor the position of the topic in the topic vector
   */
  void processImage(cv::Mat & img, int sensor) final;

  /**
   * @brief Callback Method for the state
   * @param[in] state the current state of the state machine
   */
  void updateState(std_msgs::msg::Int64::SharedPtr state) override;

  /**
  * @brief callback function for speed
  * @param p
  */
  void updateSpeed(std_msgs::msg::Float64::SharedPtr p);

  /**
   * @brief create and publish a sign message
   * @param sign_detect Detection struct of detected sign
   * @param time time it took for the processing in milliseconds
   * @param speed speed of the car at the beginning of processing
   */
  void publishSignMessage(const Detection & sign_detect, double time, double speed);

  /**
   * @brief map the sign type to the numbers wanted in the state machine
   * @param detection index of detected sign in network
   * @return index of detected sign for state machine
   */
  static int mapDetToSignType(int detection);

  /**
   * @brief calculate the area of the bounding box
   * @param height height of bounding box
   * @param width width of bounding box
   * @return area
   */
  static double getBoundingBoxArea(int height, int width);

  /**
   * @brief determine distance from sign in y direction given the area of the bounding box
   * @param area area of the bounding box
   * @return distance in y direction in mm
   */
  static double getSignDistance(double area);

  /**
   * @brief resize a given image to a wanted size
   * @param src source image
   * @param dst destination image
   * @param out_size desired output size
   * @return padding information
   */
  static std::vector<float> getLetterboxImage(
    const cv::Mat & src, cv::Mat & dst, const
    cv::Size & out_size);

  /**
   * @brief draw detected bounding boxes into the image and publish it
   * @param img image
   * @param detections detected signs
   * @param class_names file with all class names
   * @param label true if label should be printed
   */
  void publishImageWithBoundingBox(
    cv::Mat & img,
    const std::vector<Detection> & detections,
    const std::vector<std::string> & class_names,
    bool label = true);

  /**
   * @brief preprocess the output of the neural network
   * @param detections detection tensor
   * @param pad_w amount of padding in width direction
   * @param pad_h amount of padding in height direction
   * @param scale factor with which image was scaled
   * @param img_shape original image shape
   * @param conf_thres confidence threshold
   * @param iou_thres threshold for IoU
   * @return vector with all detections
   */
  static std::vector<Detection> postProcessing(
    const torch::Tensor & detections,
    float pad_w, float pad_h, float scale, const cv::Size & img_shape,
    float conf_thres = 0.4, float iou_thres = 0.5);

  /**
   * @brief scales the detected bounding boxes to fit to the original image size
   * @param data detections
   * @param pad_w amount of padding in width direction
   * @param pad_h amount of padding in height direction
   * @param scale factor with which image was scaled
   * @param img_shape img_shape original image shape
   */
  static void scaleCoordinates(
    std::vector<Detection> & data, float pad_w, float pad_h,
    float scale, const cv::Size & img_shape);

  /**
   * @brief convert bounding box format
   * @param x tensor with indices
   * @return new indices
   */
  static torch::Tensor xywh2xyxy(const torch::Tensor & x);

  /**
   * @brief convert detections from tensor to Detection struct
   * @param offset_boxes offset of the boxes
   * @param det detections
   * @param offset_box_vec offset box vector
   * @param score_vec score vector
   */
  static void tensor2Detection(
    const at::TensorAccessor<float, 2> & offset_boxes,
    const at::TensorAccessor<float, 2> & det,
    std::vector<cv::Rect> & offset_box_vec,
    std::vector<float> & score_vec);

  // /**
  //  * @brief callback for state, not implemented
  //  * @param prevState previous state
  //  * @param newState new state
  //  */
  // void onStateChange(int prevState, int newState) final;

  // variable for speed
  double current_speed_;

private:
  // module and class names
  torch::jit::script::Module module_;
  std::vector<std::string> class_names_;

  // variables for different thresholds
  float conf_threshold_;
  float iou_threshold_;

  // subscribers
  rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::Float64>::SharedPtr speed_subscriber_;
};

#endif  // PSAF_SIGN_DETECTION__SIGN_DETECTION_NODE_HPP_
```

my Cmakelist is:

````
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(psaf_sign_detection)

set(NODE_NAME "sign_detection")

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(libpsaf REQUIRED)
find_package(libpsaf_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/tuodou/wise-2023-24-ctrl-alt-defeat-feature-lane-detection/src/install/psaf_configuration/share/psaf_configuration/cmake/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/tuodou/kineto/libkineto/build")

set(psaf_configuration_DIR "/home/tuodou/wise-2023-24-ctrl-alt-defeat-feature-lane-detection/src/install/psaf_configuration/share/psaf_configuration/cmake/psaf_configurationConfig.cmake")

find_package(psaf_configuration REQUIRED)

# Explicitly set CUDA toolkit root directory
set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/cuda)

# Find CUDA
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

# find libtorch library

set(Torch_DIR /home/tuodou/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

# define sign model directory
add_compile_definitions(SIGN_MODEL_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/models")

add_executable(${NODE_NAME}
    src/${NODE_NAME}.cpp
        src/${NODE_NAME}_node.cpp
        include/psaf_sign_detection/definitions.hpp)

target_include_directories(${NODE_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${NODE_NAME}
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} 
        zbar 
        )

ament_target_dependencies(${NODE_NAME} rclcpp std_msgs libpsaf OpenCV psaf_configuration Torch)

install(TARGETS
        ${NODE_NAME}
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(DIRECTORY
        launch
        config
        DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Seeing the `undefined reference to rclcpp::shutdown,` I wonder if your ROS is appropriately installed in the first place. Please share your environment details. Also, please tell us how you installed the ROS. A link to the documentation you followed will be much more appreciated.